# JQuery validation selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am looking to use JQuery validation to enforce some client side validation of required fields etc.

The scenario is that I have dynamically populated fields but they are typically laid out the same way. I want a way to select the input field based on whether or not the label has the 'required' class. e.g. in the example below I would like to select street 1,and city but NOT street 2 input fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Street1" class="required col-sm-3 control-label">Street Address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Street1" name="Street1" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Street2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Street Address 2&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Street2" name="Street2" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="City" class="required col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="City" name="City" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I had tried this but to no avail:

```
$("label.required  :text").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id') + "  " + $(this).get(0).tagName);
});
```

Comment: Um, why don't you put the required attribute/class on the input?

Comment: Because a.)The solution has been designed that way and b.)If you think about the UI, the '*' is typically next to the text(i.e label)

Comment: a) sounds like a crappy solution and b) why would the context not be attached to the element. Look at HTML5 validation, does it work that way? Nope.

Comment: Alright mate,calm down! Just explaining the context of the issue of the provided code. Relax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted, I believe this is what you're trying to accomplished.  This code will only seek out the `:text` fields after each required label.

```
$('label.required').each(function () {
    var inputField = $(this).next('div').find('input').filter(':text');
    // Do validation of the field here
});
```

You can use the variable `inputField` to get specific data about the field. For instance, if you wanted to get the ID of the field, simply call `inputField.attr('id')`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I was actually implementing the JQuery validation so I did this in the end: `code`    $('label.required').each(function () {
    var inputField = $(this).next('div').find('input').filter(':text');
    if ($(inputField).length) {                    
                    $(inputField).rules('add', {
                        required: true
                    });
                }
}); `code`

Answer (score 0):

On form submit event you have to iterate on each label with class required and find it's next input, and validate eg :

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var return_state = true;
    $("label.required").each(function(){
    var input = $(this).next().find("input");
        //Validate your input
        //Make return_state = false in case any validation fails
    });
    return return_state;
});
```